# How do I show the code folding ribbon in Xcode 10?

Tags: xcode, xcode10

The first beta doesn't seem to have the code folding ribbon. I've checked in both Xcode Preferences and the menu (Editing -> Code Folding) and don't see an option to enable it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Preferences -> Text Editing -> Code folding ribbon. Checkmark. Done.

[image]

Comment: did they added the code folding ribbon? from-Objective-C

Comment: Now, Xcode > Settings > Text Editing